# Angular: Binding on ngIf inside ngFor

Tags: javascript, html, angular, data-binding, javascript-databinding

I am trying to populate a list with condition on each list-item, where the condition is changeable through user input. 
For example: 
app.component.ts

```
private check = true;
private some = [
    {name: 'ABC', condition: true},
    {name: 'def', condition: this.check},
    {name: 'GHI', condition: true}
];
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of some">
  <div *ngIf="item.condition">
  {{item.name}}
  </div>
</div>

<select [(ngModel)]="check">
  <option [value]="true">true</option>
  <option [value]="false">false</option>
</select>
```

Here, I have a list, `['ABC', 'def', 'GHI']`, some of whose elements I want to display always `(condition: true)` and for the rest, I have put the condition in a variable `(check)`. 
The list is being loaded correctly, but on changing the condition variable `(check)` through a dropdown, the changes are not being reflected (list is not updated). 
Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an object make the "checked" property linked to the array.
Also, you should use `<ng-container>` in order to not generate any HTML if the condition is false.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of some">
  <div *ngIf="item.condition">
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
</ng-container>

<select [(ngModel)]="myFakeForm.check">
  <option [value]="true">true</option>
  <option [value]="false">false</option>
</select>

// TS
public myFakeForm = { check: true }
public some = [
    {name: 'ABC', condition: true},
    {name: 'def', condition: this.myFakeForm.check},
    {name: 'GHI', condition: true}
];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But the above snippet is not working. Still the list is according to the initial value of condition. Can you check it again.

Comment: In that case, you may have to change the way it is done. is `some` a static array ? I mean it doesn't depends on anything, you build it in the constructor with always 3 elements, and only the 2nd one depends on the checkbox ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use public access for fields resolved in the template
2. `this.check` is passed as value not a reference to the component field - that's why it's not changing on dropdown select.

So in order to fix this, you have to pass the "check" flag somehow by reference. You could change the check from boolean to some object for example: 
`check = {value: boolean = true};` or think of more generic approach :)

Comment: I tried doing as mentioned above, but it's the same. List is not getting updated